# A 404 in all apps in Tomcat6 until conf/Catalina/localhost dir is deleted

Tags: tomcat, configuration, catalina

I'm having a strange issue.

A webapp I deployed to Tomcat 6.0.29 will work just fine. As soon as I restart Tomcat however, all my webapps will produce 404s. But, as soon as the `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost` directory with all the files is deleted and the server is restarted, the web apps will work fine again! Of course, the `[webapp].xml` files within `conf/Catalina/localhost` are just copies of `context.xml` for each respective web app, and they are not changed in the process of this shutdown/startup cycle, so I'm completely at a loss as to why Tomcat is choking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it works for other machines in the office but what did it is removing the `docBase` and `path` attributes from the context.xml file. Before solving the problem my context.xml used to look something like:

```
<Context docBase="" path="/myapp">
```

But, as the [documentation suggests](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html), the `path` attribute should be empty unless the app lives in a non-standard place. I killed both the docBase and path attributes, and it started working. No clue why it did work before the restart though...